# execute Middleware function for all query middlewares

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to Mongoose documentation about the Middlewares [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware):

> Query middleware is supported for the following Model and Query
> functions. In query middleware functions, this refers to the query.
>
> - count
> - countDocuments
> - deleteMany
> - deleteOne
> - estimatedDocumentCount
> - find
> - findOne
> - findOneAndDelete
> - findOneAndRemove
> - findOneAndReplace
> - findOneAndUpdate
> - remove
> - replaceOne
> - update
> - updateOne
> - updateMany

This means that I can write a middleware like the following one and it's going to execute whenever a findOneAndUpdate method gets called:

```js
mySchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next){
const query = this
console.log("called the pre-findOneAndUpdate middleware and hello");
})
```

Now, If I wanted to make the console.log above print its output on pre('count'), pre('replaceOne'), pre('findOneAndRemove')...etc , I will have to write too much.

is there a way to perform this by doing something like:

```js
mySchema.pre('*', function(next){
const query = this
console.log("called the pre-* middleware and hello");
})
```

where `*` means any of the methods listed above in the long list in the quote

??

Answer (score 1):

looks like there is no such possibility

you might construct it dynamically

you could grab a list of methods here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/c5893fa9f6d652d2bed08a52ad58f0f875e34bb4/lib/helpers/query/validOps.js

(I couldn't find them on the library)

and then pass that array, or construct each method with a loop:

```
// https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/c5893fa9f6d652d2bed08a52ad58f0f875e34bb4/lib/helpers/query/validOps.js
const validOps = [
    // Read
    'count',
    'countDocuments',
    'distinct',
    'estimatedDocumentCount',
    'find',
    'findOne',
    // Update
    'findOneAndReplace',
    'findOneAndUpdate',
    'replaceOne',
    'update',
    'updateMany',
    'updateOne',
    // Delete
    'deleteMany',
    'deleteOne',
    'findOneAndDelete',
    'findOneAndRemove',
    'remove'
]

mySchema.pre(validOps, function(next) {
    //...
})

// or        
for (const method of validOps) {
    mySchema.pre(method, function(next) {
        const query = this;
        console.log(`called the pre-${method} middleware and hello`);
    })
}
```

Comment: `Schema.pre()` actually [accepts an array of hook names](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-pre) (shown in the example). But there are different types of middleware ("query" and "document" being the most common), so the callback shown isn't universally useable.

Comment: @robertklep good point, I've updated the code